# since a -1 is awarded for a down vote, why not a +1 for an up vote

Tags: discussion

Since we (including myself) often comment or answer a question, yet forget to vote on the question. would getting a +1 which is small yet might help at least some of us to vote on a question especially when we answer it. Just a thought.

Comment: Getting a +1 rep point for upvoting a question would really mess up the quality of this site. **Every** question would get upvoted, which would heavily encourage bad questions *and* heavily encourage upvoting bad questions. Also, you only get a -1 for downvoting an answer, not for downvoting a question.

Comment: @El'endiaStarman good point!

Answer (score 8):

Reputation is awarded for doing *core* important things on the site. Those things are:

- Asking Good Questions
- Providing Good answers
- Having suggested Edits Approved.

That's it. This makes the core focus of the site providing and curating information. Voting is important, but for the most part the actions of voters provide themselves with relatively little change in their own reputation. It's a privilege earned, not a way to earn more privileges.

The only exception to this is downvoting answers. Originally all downvotes cost a reputation point. However, they determined that questions were not downvoted often enough and wanted to incentivize this so they took away the penalty.

This exists to provide a slight pain point to downvoting, but not not so severe that people shy away from doing it (we want you to downvote bad content). However, it is not necessary to further incentivize upvoting because plenty of people do that already as part of basic content curation. If people across the network *stopped upvoting* then some additional bonus might need to be applied, but generally people are willing to upvote simply because they've gained something (And it doesn't cost them anything).

Comment: Perhaps I didn't put enough thought into that question before asking it!

Comment: Never hurts to ask

Comment: @waxeagle The questioner has received two downvotes. So, maybe it *does* hurt to ask in this case! ;)

Comment: @Anonymous on meta it just indictes disagreement and there is no rep change on non-MSO metas.